# Unexpected end of file on a tar.gz file

Tags: c

I want sign a tar.gz file and verify the signature for do this i put a signature (in char) in my file. Then i have an another executable who check the sign and if she is good delete this, and to do that i get the content of the file whitout my signature and copy on an other file that a create.

But here is the problem, When a do this my tar.gz original file make a size of 141 and my newly created file make a size of 140. Then when a decompress them i have this error message:

> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file tar:
>
> Child returned status 1 tar:
>
> Error is not recoverable: exiting now

I think when i get the content i forgot a charactere. I tried to use clearerr or feof whitout success.

This is my code for get the content of the signed file:

```
#define SIZE_SIGNATURE (423)

int get_size(char *file)
{
  struct stat sb;
  int size = 0;

  if (stat(file, &sb) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cant access the %s file\n", file);
    return (-1);
  }
  size = sb.st_size - SIZE_SIGNATURE;
  size = size / 4;
  if (size <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The content of the file is invalid\n");
    return (-1);
  }
  return (size);
}


int *get_content(char *file, int size)
{
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  int *content = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  content = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  if (!content) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, malloc fail\n");
    return (NULL);
  }
  fp = fopen(file,"rb");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cant open %s file\n", file);
    return (NULL);
  }
  fread(content, sizeof(int), size, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return (content);
}
```

And when i have created my new file i put the content on them like this:

```
 fp = fopen(new_name, "a");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "A problem has occured during file creation.\n Cant delete signature\n");
    free(new_name);
    return;
  }
  fwrite(content, sizeof(int), size, fp);
```

Why i do: size = size / 4 (i dont know if is the thing to do)

He is a little code for understanding the thing i simply put three int in non lisible charactere

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void ecriture1()
{
  FILE* F;
  int a = 5;
  int b = 6;
  int d = 42;

  F = fopen("test.bin","wb");
  fwrite(&a,sizeof(int),1,F);
  fwrite(&d,sizeof(int),1,F);
  fwrite(&b,sizeof(int),1,F);
  fclose(F);
}

void lecture1()
{
  int *tab;
  int i = 0;
  int size;
  struct stat sb;
  FILE* F;

  stat("test.bin", &sb);
  F = fopen("test.bin","rb");
  size = sb.st_size;
  tab = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  while (i < size) {
    fread(&tab[i], sizeof(int), 1, F);
    i++;
  }
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("[i] = %d,", tab[i]);
 printf("\n");
 fclose(F);
}

int main()
{
  ecriture1();
  lecture1();
  return 0;
}
```

He is the resultat when i dont put the / 4:

> [i] = 5,[i] = 42,[i] = 6,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,[i] = 0,

And when i put / 4:

> [i] = 5,[i] = 42,[i] = 6,

EDIT:

In my programe when i delete the / 4 and i decompresse the new .tar.gz i have this error message:

> gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error
>
> tar: Child returned status 1
>
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

So i think without error on my part that i should put the / 4 but i cant explain this.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason why the size of a gzip file should be a multiple of 4 bytes, Can you explain why `get_size()` divides the file size by 4 before returning a value?

Comment: Instead of 2 steps for `malloc` then `fread`, you can simply use `mmap(2)`, would be faster too. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7E9piHcfr4).

Comment: @Mihir you think that my problem can come to this mistake ? If is the case i will try to use mmap

Comment: @Plumky, No, that would just make your work shorter and faster. As for your problem, I have the same question as aksed by @squeamish ossifrage, why `size /= 4`?

Comment: @Mihir because my contains non lisible charactère and if i dont do / 4  i get more that the realy size of my file, i dont know if you follow me, if you are anothere good technique for stack my file in a int *  I'am interested

Comment: @Mihir `mmap()` is not always faster. In most cases, it's actually going to be slower. [Per one Linus Torvalds](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0004.0/0728.html): "People love mmap() and other ways to play with the page tables to optimize away a copy operation, and sometimes it is worth it.

HOWEVER, playing games with the virtual memory mapping is very expensive
in itself. It has a number of quite real disadvantages that people tend
to ignore because memory copying is seen as something very slow, and
sometimes optimizing that copy away is seen as an obvious improvment. ..."

Comment: (cont) "

Downsides to mmap:
 - quite noticeable setup and teardown costs. And I mean _noticeable_.
   It's things like following the page tables to unmap everything
   cleanly. It's the book-keeping for maintaining a list of all the
   mappings. It's The TLB flush needed after unmapping stuff.
 - page faulting is expensive. That's how the mapping gets populated,
   and it's quite slow." IMO `mmap()` **real** advantage is much simpler code - you can access the file contents directly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, thnx for that link, I know some downsides but this was really detailed. Could you give me a little more detail on last point he mention in upsides, that may help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rounding error because you divide the size by 4.

I think the reason why you do `size / 4` is because you later do `sizeof(int) * size` and if you have 4 byte integers then that will cause your size to be 4 times larger than you want. So I think you wrote two bugs there that cancel each other out.

I would suggest you remove the `/ 4` as well as also removing the `sizeof(int) *` and thus always just let size be the byte count.

As a bonus, this will remove the rounding error that you might have which is probably the whole reason for your problem. Because `141/4 = 35,25` which will be rounded to `35`. Then `35 * sizeof(int) = 35 * 4 = 140`.

Also I would not recommend storing arbitrary binary data of arbitrary size in an array of `int` because an `int` array should have a size evenly divisible by 4. I would probably go for a `char *` or just a `void *` rather than `int *`.

Comment: Ty for your answer. At one moment, i have test to put a void * instead of a int * but if I remember correctly I had an error. Maybe a mistake of my part. For the moment i fixed my error by adding a eof character at the end. But i have test only with one size, so my problem can be not solved. In any case, i will try your solution

Comment: I am pretty confident that your problem is because you divide and then multiply by 4, which will cause your size to never be able to be anything that is not a multiple of 4. I think you will have lots of problems unless you fix that. Adding another character might _seem_ like it fixes the problem but only for size = 141, not for size  = 143. Plus, what happened to that last byte that you never read? I think you will miss it and it will feel very lonely and abandoned.

Comment: In fact i dont get the last octet because the variable "content" that i copy in my new file contains only the starting of my old file that's why I think that i dont get the eof. But I was sure it was added when i fclose the file.

Comment: I dont really understand what i must be for delete the / 4. I put my variable in void * instead of a int * and at all places where i have a 'sizeof(int)' i put a sizeof(content) (With 'content' the name of my void * variable) Its a the good right ? And for my size i should keep : sb.st-size - SIZE_SIGNATURE ?

Comment: If `content` is a pointer then `sizeof(content)` should be 4 bytes if you have a 32 bit system and 8 bytes on a 64 byte system. So I would not recomment you use that at all. Keep your size so that it represents the number of bytes to read/write because that makes things much simpler. Then there is no need to even multiply with sizeof anything. When you malloc, just malloc `size` because that is the number of bytes you want to allocate.

Comment: Its doesn't work, I'm doing something wrong. I have delete the / 4 My size do 141 after removing the SIZE_SIGNATURE. Then i malloc my void * content like this: content = malloc(size); Then i fread like this: fread(content, sizeof(content), size, fp); and my fwrite is like this: fwrite(content, sizeof(content), size, fp). The result is that now my new file make a size of 8

Comment: `content` is a pointer and on a 64bit system that will be 8 bytes long. So I dont think you should use `sizeof(content)` in your `fread/fwrite` but replace that with 1. The fact that you only got 8 bytes is strange though.

Comment: Its so strange, i remplace all my sizeof(content) with 1 ans after executing my programe the new file have the good size, but when i decompress them, i have this error: invalid compressed data--length error